# Heroku add-ons 'Logentries' & 'FlyData' query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, robots.txt, logentries

I have a Ruby on Rails web app hosted on Heroku and I've setup Logentries add-on which sets up alarms for '**High Response Time**'.

Lately, I have started getting emails for '**ALERT High Response Time**', which mention that the high response time was triggered for

`heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/robots.txt"`

Now, I know that Search Engines like Google, Microsoft use the robots.txt to ignore the pages that should not be indexed. Is there any other reason, why this file would be accessed?

Please correct me if I am missing something here.

Oh, and I am using the free version of Heroku i.e. 1 worker for website-content and I have 1 worker which runs periodic jobs using the Scheduler.

**Query #2**-

What's wrong with my application, when I get the following email from Logentries, with subject - '**ALERT Exit Timeout**'

`Exit timeout: Heroku/my-app
2014-10-13 18:53:56.351
188 <45>1 2014-10-13T18:53:56.053533+00:00 heroku web.1 - - Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM`

**Query #3-**

I also installed the FlyData add-on trial to see how it works. I get emails with the subject - '**[FlyData-Alert] (myapp) Application Error notification**'.
The email says-
`We noticed the following error logs on your application (myapp) :
2014-10-08T23:59:53.042662+00:00 app[scheduler.3266]: ** [NewRelic][10/08/14 23:59:53 +0000 21fd815f-5e08-42ab-80d8-4771ea1593c7 (2)] INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation`

I think this email is triggered because of the INFO message from New Relic, which says - Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation. The FlyData add-on probably looks at the keyword 'Error' and triggers the email alert.

Comment: Some unfriendly robots (like email harvesters) will request robots.txt just to find out which pages you want hidden, so they can make a point of crawling them. I don't know if this is what is happening to you, but it's a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Query #2:  Heroku - Exit timeout: Heroku/my-app

According to Heroku's documentation,
"A process failed to exit within 10 seconds of being sent a SIGTERM indicating that it should stop. The process is sent SIGKILL to force an exit."

There is a complete list of Heroku Errors codes, including this one, that can be found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r12-exit-timeout

If you're using webrick to run your application on Heroku, you should try to switch to using 'thin' to see if that helps: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#webserver.
or see the previous answer on stackoverflow here:
[Rails app hosted on heroku: Error R12 (Exit timeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838824/rails-app-hosted-on-heroku-error-r12-exit-timeout)

Hope this helps.

Michael